# Android layout xml causing npe

Tags: android, xml, layout, nullpointerexception, dialog

I have a problem with a null pointer exception and I dont understand why. Please dont mark this as a dup of the thread "null pointer exception and how to fix it" as that thread is not relevant at all.

I do know what an npe is. And thus, I dont need that explained.

So, to the problem:

I have a dialog with a custom layout

The layout xml file contains a linearlayout with a tablelayout inside. When I completly remove the tablelayout the npe goes away. Thus, I conclude that it has to be something wrong with the XML.

Android studio however, gives no errors.

Here is a link to the xml in question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879730/null-pointer-exception-when-trying-to-open-a-dialogbox-from-fragment-android

Edit:

Here is the full XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:text="Alarm info"
    android:id="@+id/alarm_fragment_dialog_title"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="376dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Enhetens navn:"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Ctrl-O"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Tidspunkt:"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Ctrl-O"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Posisjon:"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Ctrl-O"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit 2: Adding Java code

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alarm_details_dialog);

        dialog.show();

   }
```

Comment: Maybe share your xml too if you feel that is causing the issue.

Comment: Posting from cellphone, but I can try to copy from my other thread. Sec

Comment: I will post it in this thread later. My stupid Iphone will not let me copy the text from the linked thread. Will update when I am at the conputer.

Comment: Let me know when you do that. I have a few suggestions.

Comment: I have now added the xml

Comment: Also, add the java code for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is definitely with your `<TableLayout>` element. Even in the layout editor it is showing NPE without any need to run. I noticed this might be because of the following setup:

```
-TableLayout -> height = 376dp
    -TableRow -> height = match_parent
         -textview -> height = match_parent
         -textview -> height = match_parent
    -TableRow -> height = match_parent
         -textview -> height = match_parent
         -textview -> height = match_parent
    -TableRow -> height = match_parent
         -textview -> height = match_parent
         -textview -> height = match_parent
```

The above hierarchy of repeated `<TableLayout>` children requesting height to be `match_parent` is what I believe is the true cause of error. I don't know the exact issue but the renderer reported height related NPE.

This can be solved if your `<TableLayout>` has a `wrap_content` based hierarchy. So, below is the updated `<TableLayout>` code. I also updated the width of `<TableRow>` elements to `0dp` since they were using `layout_weight` property.

```
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="376dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="Enhetens navn:"
                android:textColor="#000"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="Ctrl-O"
                android:textColor="#000"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="Tidspunkt:"
                android:textColor="#000"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="Ctrl-O"
                android:textColor="#000"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="Posisjon:"
                android:textColor="#000"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="Ctrl-O"
                android:textColor="#000"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Hope this helps~

Comment: I will try it out. Strange that I dont see any error msgs in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

To set custom layout to a dialog, you don't need to get reference of your activity like you are doing in following code:

```
dialog.setContentView(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_datalog));
```

You, just need to reference your layout file:

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_file_name); // not the id of your root container, but the name of your xml file itself.
```

Try with above change and if your get errors post the logcat.

Comment: Already tried that. Same NPE, but when i remove the tablelayout from the XML file, thus leaving only the linearlayout in place, it works fine. Without no errors in logcat, or npe.

Comment: @ThomasHolden Let me try it.

Comment: JUST RAN IT and bloody hell there was an NPE! I'm gonna find it out man...wait!

Comment: It has to be something in the xml. I just dont see it... Thanks for trying btw.